# Split element on line break with GoQuery

Tags: go, goquery

I'm trying to get content from page with GoQuery, but for some reasons I can't do split on line break (br).

The HTML, looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>I'm skipped</li>

    <li> 
        Text Into  - <p>Whatever</p>
        <p>
            Line 1<br />
            Line 2<br />
            Line 3<br />
            Line 4<br />
            Line N
        </p>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

Go code:

```
doc, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(res.Body)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

doc.Find("ul").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {

    str := s.Find("li p").Next().Text()

    fmt.Println(str, "--")

})
```

For some reason I'm not able to get each line, separated by break in p tag, as single item.Output of code above is:

```
Line1Line2Line3Line4LineN--
```

But the output I'm trying to achieve should looks like this:

```
Line1--
Line2--
Line3--
Line4--
LineN--
```

Since I'm Go newbie, please let me know in comment If something is not clear, so I will try to explain It as much as I know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Text()` will:

> Text gets the combined text contents of each element in the set of
>   matched elements, including their descendants.

So what you actually want to do is get the contents and the filter out any br tags.  As dave's answer states there is new line characters in there so I've also trimmed those:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
    "strings"
)

var input string = `
<ul>
    <li>I'm skipped</li>

    <li> 
        Text Into  - <p>Whatever</p>
        <p>
            Line 1<br />
            Line 2<br />
            Line 3<br />
            Line 4<br />
            Line N
        </p>
    </li> 
</ul>
`

func main() {
    doc, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(strings.NewReader(input))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    doc.Find("ul").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {

        p := s.Find("li p").Next()
        p.Contents().Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
            if !s.Is("br") {
                fmt.Println(strings.TrimSpace(s.Text()), "--")
            }

        })

    })
}
```

Produces:

```
Line 1 --
Line 2 --
Line 3 --
Line 4 --
Line N --
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran the code you showed, and I am getting newlines in the string.  Assuming you are on the latest version of goquery you should be as well, *unless* your html is not

```
<p>
    Line 1<br />
    Line 2<br />
    Line 3<br />
    Line 4<br />
    Line N
</p>
```

but is actually something like:

```
<p>
    Line 1<br />Line 2<br />Line 3<br />Line 4<br />Line N
</p>
```

(keeping in mind that when you open chrome dev tools, for example, it is probably *displaying it* as the former, even if the actual source is that latter)

in which case, this is expected behaviour:

```js
let html_1 = $(`<p>
        Line 1<br />
        Line 2<br />
        Line 3<br />
        Line 4<br />
        Line N
    </p>`);

let html_2 = $(`<p>
        Line 1<br />Line 2<br />Line 3<br />Line 4<br />Line N
    </p>`);
    
console.log({html1: html_1.text(), html2: html_2.text()});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To resolve, you could probably just do:

```
p := s.Find("li p").Next()
p.SetHtml(strings.Replace(p.Html(), "<br />", "<br />\n", -1)).Text()
```

although, you may have to play with whether to use `<br/>` or `<br />` or `<br>` as I'm not sure how it will render it.

Comment: Thanks Dave for response, I tried your solution and I got error `multiple-value p.Html() in single-value context`.Probably because `p.Html()` has multiple return arguments, I guess ? Btw what do you think about solution I found in meanwhile ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I managed to find one solution.Not sure If It's right way to go, so If someone have something better - please share It.

So I basically, store value of `li p` as HTML, and then use `strings.Split` to break on each `br` tag, and since `strings.Split` returns slice of strings, I just loop over It.

```
title, err := s.Find("li p").Next().Html()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

splittedTitles := strings.Split(title, "<br/>")

for _, str := range splittedTitles {
    fmt.Println(str, "--")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be better if you just replace `<br/>` with '\n' or '--' before your call `.Text()` method.

```
    // html is the result of `.Html()` method
    str := strings.Replace(html, "<br/>", "\\n", -1)
    doc, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(strings.NewReader(str))
    if err != nil {
        return ""
    }
    return doc.Text()
```